# What is this LC circuit for?

Tags: filter, schematics

I was looking through an STM32 development board schematic and found a circuit I don't understand.

The circuit is a ferrite bead (120 Ohms at 100MHz) in parallel with 4 100nF capacitors. This is between the USB connector's ground and shield, and the circuit ground:

[image: Circuit]

I assume the ferrite bead is to keep noise from entering/leaving the USB cable, but I'm not sure what the capacitors are for. I'd assume whatever noise the ferrite bead blocks would just go straight through the capacitors.

My only thought is that it's some sort of notch filter, but I'm not sure why you'd want that on a USB port ground.

Pictures of the board seem to show all components are fitted:

[image: PCB]

Comment: Look again - three of those capacitors are called 100 nH not 100 nF. AND it's impedance is 120 ohms at 100 MHz (not Hz). In short, don't trust that circuit because it was drawn without due care.

Comment: Which STM32 developement board would that be?

Comment: @Andyaka Oops, I fixed the 100Hz thing. They are definitely capacitors at 100nF, the schematic just renders it weirdly.

Comment: the schematic renders what is in the component value.

Comment: @Justme The board is a 32F746GDISCOVERY: https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html

Comment: @JonRB The 1 and the F make it look like a H

Comment: I dunno why you would want a notch filter in a connection between the USB connector's GND and shield pins and circuit ground.

Comment: @user2248702 then the program is doing its job, whoever captured the schematic should have added one more grid space between the components. Loads of room so zero excuse

Comment: @SteveSh I agree that looks very VERY odd.. unless they wanted provision to fit either an L or a C but both?  that's just going to cause problems

Comment: Notice how there is a separate USB connector ground plane. My best guess is the DC current path is routed via ferrite bead L7 to the top copper ground plane. As it is the only path for DC currents, in case of some short circuit, it will also double as a fuse if it burns up. But as the high speed USB differential pair needs a solid reference ground plane, the capacitors are there to connect the connector ground plane to the global ground plane, so only AC currents can pass the capacitors so the differential signal has a solid reference plane and AC return current path.

Comment: Caps may be for ESD.  Because of the physical layout of the part, it may be helpful to have more than one. This could have been something that was arrived at empirically during ECM testing.

Comment: But what justme said is also very plausible. By having caps there, they have the ability to do ESD and EMC tuning. With 100nF, they might as well put in zero ohm jumpers. But if they had trouble passing radiated emissions they could experiment with different caps and ferrite beads to find something that works.